# In ngFor loop how can i just select one specific html element and get reference on it?

Tags: angular, menu, ngfor

My html

```
<div class="wrapper2">
  <div *ngFor="let menu of sidebarService.currentMenus$ | async">
    <h3 (click)="expanded()">
      {{ menu.label }}
    </h3>
    <ul *ngFor="let menuItem of menu.child">
      <li * ngIf="isExpanded">
        <a [href]="menuItem.route"> {{ menuItem.label }}</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

My menu structure what come from service looks like:

```
  [
    {
      id: '1',
      icon: 'search',
      label: 'search',
      child: [
        {
          id: '11',
          icon: '',
          label: 'my-search',
          route: 'search/search'
        },

      ]
    },
    {
      id: '2',
      icon: 'mail',
      label: 'about',
      child: [
        {
          id: '21',
          icon: '',
          label: 'about me',
          route: 'about/about'
        }],
    }
  ];
```

How can i avhive that the expand function just hide the menu which label i am clicking on,not both.There are two menu in the array. isExpanded just a boolean and expand function just set the opposite of isExpanded.

Comment: You could add an `expanded` property to your `menu` and change it based on actions. Do you need to have more than one label expanded?

Comment: with ngFor's index can i somehow add class to it and get reference?

Answer (score 1):

You need to add expanded property in you data

```
[
  {
    id: '1',
    icon: 'search',
    label: 'search',
    expanded: false,
    child: [
      {
        id: '11',
        icon: '',
        label: 'my-search',
        route: 'search/search'
      },

    ]
  },
  {
    id: '2',
    icon: 'mail',
    label: 'about',
    expanded: false,
    child: [
      {
        id: '21',
        icon: '',
        label: 'about me',
        route: 'about/about'
      }],
  }
];
```

and then use it like this

```
<div class="wrapper2">
  <div *ngFor="let menu of sidebarService.currentMenus$ | async">
    <h3 (click)="menu.expanded = !menu.expanded">
      {{ menu.label }}
    </h3>
    <ul *ngIf="menu.expanded">
      <li *ngFor="let menuItem of menu.child">
        <a [href]="menuItem.route"> {{ menuItem.label }}</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```